Error: [Reanimated] Babel plugin exception: TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'workletNumber')
After trying to use reaniamted with expo I seem to have corrupted my project? Even when uninstalling it complains that there are references to react-native-reanimated. Anyone having a similar issue?
Error: [Reanimated] Babel plugin exception: TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'workletNumber')
